# Connecting Route 53 to EC2 and port

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, port, amazon-route53

I'm having trouble connecting Route 53 to an EC2 with an app running on the 8080 port. Currently, I can hit and use the app using `http://<EC2 name>:8080/<endpoint path>`, but I obviously want to hit it with a domain name instead.

I created a host zone .com, created a record, used record type A and set the ip as the ipv 4 provided by the EC2. I then copied the four ns- route traffic names across to the nameservers in registered domain. Unfortunately, when I hit `www.<domain name>/<endpoint path>` I get 'did not match any documents'.

Is this something I'm missing when setting up the route 53 or is it an issue to do with the port?

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: Should be relatively easy following this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-ec2-instance.html) (assuming you have a hosted zone configured correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple enough in the end, I just used sudo java -Dserver.port=80 -jar .jar & No setting up the code differently, just setting it to use port 80. Also found out I had to use sudo, otherwise you get a permission denied when allocating to the root.

Comment: Yes, that will work, but keep in mind that that should only be used for internal/proof-of-concept/throwaway setup; you dont wan't your app to run as root only because you want to bind to port 80

Answer (score 2):

> but I obviously want to hit it with a domain name instead

You **can't** do that with Route53, as R53 is just a DNS resolver: domain name -> IP address (not port).

You have to do redirection of port 80 to 8080 on your **instance**, not on Route53. A common way is through **Nginx** that you have to setup and configure on the instance as a reverse proxy.

Comment: I should be able to change the port that needs hitting as its a springboot app. So if I change the port to 80 it will just automatically hit it by default by just using the domain name set up? I'll have a look at Nginx as well, thanks.

Comment: @HywelGriffiths Yes. By default browsers use port 80 for http and 443 for https.

Comment: Cheers @Marcin - first time setting up a web app so picking all these tips up. Something about port 80 flittered in the back of my mind but couldn't quite remember!